# Bootstrap vertical navpills only load iframe on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am currently working on a little layout on my website using Bootstrap's vertical nav pillls

```
  <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
  </div>
```

The problem that I have however that 2 of these tabs are loading iframes and unfortunately they are really slowing down my overall loading times. Is there a method to load the iframe ONLY if a tab/pill containing an iframe is being triggered?

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe loads separately from the main page, so it shouldn't slow down the main page, unless there is a bandwidth constraint.

One solution could be to dynamically load the iframes only when they are needed. To do this you start with an iframe that has no `src` attribute:

```
<iframe data-src="/iframe_page1.php"></iframe>
```

here I store the wanted value of `src` in a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). The when, for instance, the link for the messages is clicked, you can set the iframe `src` attribute:

```
$("#v-pills-messages-tab").on("shown.bs.tab", function() {
    let iframe = $(this);
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data('src'));
});
```

That should then load the iframe.

I haven't actually tested this code, but I hope you understand the general idea?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I will definitely check it out! Happy Holidays my friend